# Javascript: Problemas creando la funcion isString usando el operador "typeof"

Tags: javascript, funciones, function, operador, formato-condicional

La actividad a desarrollar es la siguiente:

Crear una función llamada isString que toma tres argumentos (a, b, c). Esta función hace lo siguiente:

Utiliza el operador typeof y una comparación de igualdad estricta para comprobar si el tipo de los tres parámetros a, b y c es una cadena.
Si cada argumento es una cadena, devuelve las cadenas del mensaje.
Si alguno de los tres parámetros no es una cadena, devuelve el mensaje, no cadenas.

Es la primera vez que trabajo con esta función y me gustaría me pudieran ayudar a resolver el problema.

Desde ya muchas gracias.

---

adjunto lo que estuve avanzando. Muchas gracias.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estupendo, solo falta que aportes lo que has intentado, con ello podemos terminar de comprender lo que expones y la forma de ayudarte.

Comment: Hola Juan, acabo de compartir la imagen de lo trabajado. Gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] ya realizar el [tour]. Para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, debes incluir un [mcve], donde expliques lo que has intentado, el problema encontrado y el resultado esperado. El publicar sólo el enunciado de tu tarea, da a entender que estás buscando que alguien la resuelva por ti. Este tipo de preguntas terminan cerradas. Si crees que puedes agregar el código de lo que has intentado, haz clic en [edit]. El código debe ir en formato texto (copiar y pegar) y no como imagen. Saludos

Comment: Creo que a tu pregunta le falta algo mas de desarrollo consulta [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente lo que estas preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Con un If Talvez ,Asi:

```
function isStrinig (a,b,c){

if(typeof(a)==="string" && typeof(b) === "string" && typeof(c) === "string"){
    console.log(a,' ',b,' ',c);
}else{
    console.log('No es una Cadena');
}
isStrinig('a',2,'c');
if(typeof module !== 'undefined'){
module.exports = isStrinig;
```

}